# display page info when link is sent on apps (eg whatsapp)

Tags: html, css, web

I want the main info of my web page to show when the link is shared on apps, just like in the screenshot attached from whatsapp. The app should provide a description of the page from the link.
What html tag am I looking for? [whatsapp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzGg6.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to review HTML meta tags, Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the meta tags to achieve your goal.

For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="Put here your webpage main text">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="wepage url here">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YOUR WEBPAGE NAME">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="IMAGE you wanna show in the main link" content="url of the image">
```

After that you should be able to link your webpage url into apps and show the content you want.

best regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, works